# parsing through a dynamic json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm building an import system that will used for importing product from various vendors, and the app has to conform to whatever the vendor gives us, so there's no normalized column. I have a mongodb collection has a mapping of what goes to what

for example, vendor A has sku binded to code but vendor B may call it itemCode

so when I'm parsing my json data, how would I be able to just dynamically tell my app that sku is that field?

I'd like to be able to do like what I'm doing for vendors using xml which is like

```
doc.LoadXml(content);
XmlNodeList itemPath = doc.SelectNodes(Config.XmlItemPath);

foreach (XmlNode item in itemPath)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item[MapToValue("CurrencyCode")]?.InnerText);
}
```

I haven't seen such a way with Json.NET so I'm sorta lost on how I can easily parse through this data.

Comment: Do you know what each vendor will call it? Or you're assuming that any property with "code" in it is the one you're looking for?

Comment: I just know after I create the mapping for it but that mapping is in a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) API.  You could write very similar code with it:

```
JToken root = JToken.Parse(jsonContent);
IEnumerable<JToken> itemTokens = root.SelectTokens(Config.JsonItemPath);
foreach (JToken item in itemTokens)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item[MapToValue("CurrencyCode")]?.ToString());
}
```

[API Reference](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/N_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq.htm)

Comment: interesting, I'll give this a shot

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just convert the json to xml seeing as xml has a bit more flexibility in .NET

```
var doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(content, "root");

XmlNodeList itemPath = doc.SelectNodes(Config.XmlItemPath);

if (itemPath == null) throw new Exception("Invalid XML Path.");
{
    foreach (XmlNode row in itemPath)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(row[GetJsonProperty("Brand")]?.InnerText);
    }
}
```

this does exactly what I want now, I'm open to hear how to do it without converting to xml but this will get me moving onward with my work.